# mysql filter using like from another table

Tags: mysql

I know how to do this with cursors, but am wondering if it's possible without.

I'm analyzing traffic to my website, keeping track of IP address, requested URL, agent, referrer, hostname, etc.  I'm using a stored procedure to perform the insert and logic.

From traffic I've already logged, I've identified additional actions I want to take based on the details of the visit:

1 - If the request is for /wp-* , /test, /admin, /backup, /old, /wordpress* (and more), this is an exploit probe (this isn't a wordpress site).  I want the IP address blacklisted automatically.

2 - If the request is a social media hit (visible via the URL requested and/or the referrer), our marketing person wants the system to send her a text message immediately.  It inserts info into the po_box table, which sets off a trigger to send.

3 - If the agent is python-requests* or one of multiple bots ignoring my robots.txt, I want the IP address blacklisted automatically.

I'm looking for something along the lines of "if requested_url like (select exploit_prefix from known_exploits)" or "if requested_url like (select sm_query from social_med_links) or http_referrer like (select sm_referral from social_media_links)" or "if http_referrer like (select bot_ref from bad_bots) or user_agent like (select bot_agent from bad_bots)"

I'm doing it with cursors right now, but am looking for a more elegant way.  Even if it's slower than cursors (would be surprising), I'm curious if it can be done.

@Sloan Thrasher:  I intentionally didn't go into details about how the back-end works.  It works as it is, and discussing it derails from the actual question (such as the @danblack comment that the exploits I identified aren't exploit probes.  I have determined that they are, based on evidence.)  I'm asking if it's possible to move away from cursors, and use (hopefully more efficient) queries.

One of the first functions is to log the page visit, which determines if the request is violating the site, or the IP address has already been blacklisted.  If the IP is in the blacklist table (either previously or because of the current request), the server passes a 403.  I double check every new address added to the blacklist, and move to .htaccess if appropriate, or change the rules if not appropriate.

```
create table bad_bots (
    bot_ref varchar(16) comment 'use like %xxx% compare',
    bot_agent varchar(16) comment 'use like %xxx% compare',
    blacklist_comment varchar(32) comment 'push to blacklist table'
);
```

Some of the bot_ref entries:

```
http://pizza-imperia.com/
```

Some of the bot_agent entries:

```
%MJ12bot%
%NetcraftSurveyAgent%
%Uptimebot%
%zgrab%
%python-requests%

create table blacklist (
    blacklist_ip varchar(32) primary key,
    blacklist_added datetime not null default now(),
    blacklist_comment varchar(32)
);

create table known_exploits(
    exploit_prefix varchar(64) primary key comment 'use like xxx% compare,  
    blacklist_comment varchar(32) comment 'push to blacklist table'
);
```

A partial list of the prefixes.  @danblack - each is an attempt to access aspects of the site which are common exploit avenues.  NO ONE has any right to access my /admin directory without express authorization, and legitimate content scans know that.  This list has been developed by looking up the IPs who have made these requests, and they exist in multiple blacklists for detailed exploit probes.

```
/admin%
/adminer.php%
/xmlrpc.php%
/demo%
/backup%
/test%
/main%
/new%
/old%
/wp/wp-login.php%
/wordpress/wp-login.php%
```

(Identifies hits off of social media accounts or google/yahoo/bing/chamber of commerce, etc.)

```
create table social_media_links (
    sm_referral varchar(32) comment 'use like %xxx% compare,
    sm_query varchar(32) comment 'use like %xxx% compare',
    sm_owner varchar(16) comment 'use for po_box'
);
```

A partial list of the sm_referral entries:

```
%.facebook.com/%
%.instagram.com/%
%.yelp.com/%
%thurstonchamber.com%
```

Only one sm_query so far:

```
%?fbclid=%

create table page_visits (
    visit_ip_address varchar(32),
    visit_time datetime not null default now(),
    visit_url varchar(128),
    visit_agent varchar(64),
    visit_referrer varchar(128)
);

create procedure sp_log_page_visit (
    IN var_visit_ip_address varchar(32),
    IN var_visit_url varchar(128),
    IN var_visit_agent varchar(64),
    IN var_visit_referrer varchar(128)
)
begin
    declare is_blacklisted int default 0;

    insert into page_visits (visit_ip_address, visit_url, visit_agent, visit_referrer)
        values (var_visit_ip_address, var_visit_url, var_visit_agent, var_visit_referrer);

    # I'M CURRENTLY USING A CURSOR FOR THIS...LOOKING FOR SIMPLER QUERY SIMILAR TO...
    if(var_visit_agent like (select bot_agent from bad_bots where bot_agent is not null) 
    or var_visit_referrer like (select bot_ref from bad_bots where bot_ref is not null)) then

        insert ignore into blacklist (blacklist_ip) values (var_visit_ip_address);
        set is_blacklisted = 1;
    end if;

    # I'M CURRENTLY USING A CURSOR FOR THIS...LOOKING FOR SIMPLER QUERY SIMILAR TO...
    if(var_visit_url like (select exploit_prefix from known_exploits)) then
        insert ignore into blacklist (blacklist_ip) values (var_visit_ip_address);
        set is_blacklisted = 1;
    end if;

    # I'M CURRENTLY USING A CURSOR FOR THIS...LOOKING FOR SIMPLER QUERY SIMILAR TO...
    if(var_visit_referrer like (select sm_referral from social_media_links)
    or (var_visit_url like (select sm_query from social_media_links)) then
        # performs multiple actions to add new entry into po_box table
    end if

    select is_blacklisted;
end ;;
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the schema of the table(s). Do you have tables listing the exploit urls, social media, and bots? If so, add those schemas as well. Seems like a simple SQL query would do what you want. Also, describe what should happen to "blacklist" a IP address.

Comment: 1 - these requests aren't exploits, just an attempt at hitting content that isn't there - attempting to match will cost you CPU. Configure your webserver to not log these 404 and focus on your real customers.
2. might be able to do this with fail2ban or a specific web server configuration.
3. are you seeing an impact from these bad bots? If so fail2ban otherwise ignore.

Comment: I purposely avoided too much detail, which will move away from the question being asked.  
@Sloan Thrasher - What happens after the address is determined as proper for blacklist is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @danblack - Yes, these are exploit probes.  Whether anyone else thinks they should be considered as such is outside the scope of the question

Comment: To store all logs in a database is a waste of CPU / storage. Only requirement 2 -  has a needed storage requirement on the referred URL, and its not necessary to be a SQL database. This isn't about rights, requests for stuff that doesn't exist 404 will happen and can't be changed, once you start focusing on it you end up using more CPU and storage just eliminating it from the logs than the time taken to show 404 a few more times (and no security benefit). Use fail2ban for 403 authenticated content but something other than /admin would be a bit more hidden.

Comment: @danblack - Thank you for your thoughts, but I'm asking if there is a way to do what I want, not whether you think I should be doing what I want.  That is precisely why I initially asked the question without any of the schema, and very little detail.  Both of your answers are completely out of the scope of the question.  I have more comments about your last post, but each is out of the scope of the question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have a table `known_exploits`, a simple query will determine whether or not to blacklist a particular IP. Here's an example for your first query:

```
IF ((SELECT count(`exploit_prefix`) as `numfound`
    FROM `known_exploits`
    where `exploit_prefix` like var_visit_url) > 0)
    THEN
        insert ignore into `blacklist` (`blacklist_ip`) values (var_visit_ip_address);
        set is_blacklisted = 1;
ENDIF;
```

Comment: ...Hanging my head...feel kind of foolish.
Proof that you can get too close to your code.  Had I not been stuck in a mental loop, of course I'd have done this.

Comment: I think we have all done that at one time or another (or many times in my case ;)